# Python/pandas error only when running, not debugging

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter a df's rows according to whether the value in a specific column startsiwth the value of another specific column.
I do that with this line:

```
 df = df[df.apply(lambda x: x.A.startswith(x.B), axis=1)]
```

In the PyCharm debugger, this runs correctly and does what I want... but when I try to run the code outside the debugger, I get: "TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [bool]" on that line.

There is indeed a datetime column in the df. It's neither A nor B, so I don't see why it needs to be converted to bool at any time.

What's going on? How can I fix this?

Edit: full stacktrace:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3011, in __getitem__
return self.where(key)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 9287, in where
cond, other, inplace, axis, level, errors=errors, try_cast=try_cast
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 9046, in _where
cond = cond.astype(bool)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5877, in astype
new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 631, in astype
return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 427, in apply
applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 2291, in astype
return super().astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 673, in astype
values = astype_nansafe(vals1d, dtype, copy=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py", line 1041, in astype_nansafe
raise TypeError(f"cannot astype a datetimelike from [{arr.dtype}] to [{dtype}]")
TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [bool]
```

Comment: Not sure what the `.apply` method is needed for here, but have you tried just `df = df[df.A.str.startswith(x.B)]`? Also, please provide the full stack trace of that error, so we know which lines are affected.

Comment: Yes, I tried without the apply: KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,\n              ...\n              nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],\n             dtype='float64', length=31837)] are in the [columns]"

Comment: Please update your question with the stack trace and any additional errors you may have encountered.